# Listar dados do BD usando echo (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Olá, eu tenho esse código:

```
<<?php 
include("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$buscarusuario = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_clientes WHERE ID=:id");
$buscarusuario->bindValue(":id",2,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$buscarusuario->execute();

$linha = $buscarusuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($linha as $listar) {
echo "E-mail: ".$listar->email."</br>";
var_dump($listar);
}
```

O meu problema está sendo que o `echo` não é exibido na tela, testei com o `var_dump` e ele mostra os dados do BD. Usando `FETCH_ASSOC` da certo normal, porém como estou aprendendo PDO, queria fazer isso usando também o `FETCH_OBJ`, porém, como eu disse, o `echo` não é exibido na tela. Alguém tem uma ideia de porque isso ocorre ou qual outra forma de exibir? Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta isso

```
 <?php 
    include("conexao.php");
    $pdo = conectar();

    $buscarusuario = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_clientes WHERE ID=:id");
    $buscarusuario->bindValue(":id",2,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $buscarusuario->execute();

    while($listar = $buscarusuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "E-mail: ".$listar->email."</br>";
    var_dump($listar);
    }
```

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou, muito obrigado mesmo, mas só mais uma coisa, por eu estar tratando a variável como um objeto, pelo fato de estar usando `FETCH_OBJ`, o `foreach` não pode ser aplicado?

Answer (score 0):

maninho vc tem q tratar o resultado se nao me engano, joga a variavel que recebe o resultado em um array e depois faz o foreach no array